# Uniform lighting when there are multiple light sources

Tags: java, libgdx, jbox2d

I'm writing a 2d game where there are walls and the NPCs can only see what is within their line of site. To do this I'm using Box2dLights so the walls create shadows.

The problem I'm having is that each NPC has a light. This means that the lighting increases where multiple lights crossover. Instead I would just like the same amount of light to hit the areas that are visible to the NPCs.

To summarise I would like there to be a peak amount of light to be reached. If any more lights are added then the light doesn't increase past this threshold.

Here is an example of multiple lights crossing over.

[image: Multiple lights crossing over]

How might I go about doing this?